# Magic Mouse battery level broken in Lion?

Tags: macos, battery, mouse

After upgrading to Lion my Magic Mouse's level indicator seems to be broken.

For the whole week it was reporting solid 100% on a pair of used batteries that were about 65% before upgrading. I swapped the batteries naively hoping it'll change anything and it actually did. It's now solid 95%!

Screens from both system preferences and Bluetooth icon in the menu bar:

[image: mouse battery level in prefs]
[image: mouse battery level in Bluetooth]

What's interesting, [iStat Pro dashboard widget](http://islayer.com/apps/istatpro/) seems to be reporting a correct level:

[image: mouse battery level in iStat Pro]

Has anyone noticed such a problem? Or maybe even found a solution to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not the only one. Mine says the same - 100%. This is a bug. The terminal command for querying the battery percentage (probably what iStat Pro uses) reports: "BatteryPercent" = 82

For bluetooth mouse:

```
ioreg -n "BNBMouseDevice" | grep -i "batterypercent"
```

For Apple bluetooth keyboard:

```
ioreg -n "AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard" | grep -i "batterypercent"
```

I've posted this in the Apple Bug reporter. Hopefully it will be fixed in an future Lion update.

Here is another thread discussing the same issue.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3211868

Comment: That explains it then. Let's hope for a prompt hotfix to Lion.

Comment: I can confirm this too. The Bluetooth Menu and System Preferences report 66%, but it's actually 46%.

Comment: Here on Lion 10.7.2 the bluetooth menulet reports 7% and `ioreg` 20% — so I guess it got *fixed too much.* :-D

Comment: Yep. Still there in 10.7.2. I haven't had any response back from Apple about the ticket either. I'm interested in where this other number is coming from. Where are they getting it?

Comment: In 2018, 10.12.6 reports keyboard battery percentages differently from menu bar/system preferences to ioreg. In my case, currently ioreg reports 77% while system prefs and the menu bar report 100%.

Comment: I love how I was "hopeful" that Apple would solve this with Lion in 2011. 7 years later… it's still not fixed! LOL!